# Display selectedvalues of listbox as label - multiple values

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

I have got a list box called lstPTLNameDHOD which has multiple PTL names which gets selected using Ctrl.  I want to display the selected names in a label or some way that the person submitted the form can see who exactly they are submitting it for.

My problem is I can only get one name to display on the label.

```
// Items collection
foreach (ListItem item in lstPTLNameDHOD.Items)
{
   if (item.Selected)
   {
       lbl1stPTL.Text = item.Value.ToString();

   }
}
```

This is being called on post back on the reason dropdown being changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only getting one name to display because your current code would always display name of the last item that is selected.

I don't have a visual studio handy but you could try this:

```
StringBuilder sbText = new StringBuilder();
// Items collection
foreach (ListItem item in lstPTLNameDHOD.Items)
{
   if (item.Selected)
   {
       lbl1stPTL.Text = sbText.Append(item.Value.ToString()).ToString();
   }
}
```

You can probably refine this by adding a space or a comma between two item names but I hope you get the idea and it helps!

Again, sorry for not having VS handy!